# Use add_weighted_edges_from to build graph with networkx from large file

Tags: python, networkx

My file looks like this:

```
A,B,50
A,C,34
C,D,55
```

First two columns as the ends of undirected edges and the third column is the weight.

I try to use the following code to import the data:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist("file.csv", delimiter=",")
```

And this one to display the result:

```
G.edges(data=True)
```

It works great for small size files but my file contains about 50 millions lines. It took a while running and got Killed every time. Is there any better way to do it? Like maybe import seperate small files? Once the graph is returned by nx.read_weighted_edgelist("file.csv", delimiter=","), is there any way to add more edges to it?

Comment: You are running out of memory.  Depending on the edge data it might take more than 10GB to hold the graph in memory with NetworkX.

Comment: So if the memory is not enough there is no better way to do it? file.csv is 2.7GB actually

Comment: Unfortunately the only option right now with NetworkX is to store the graph in memory.  And that expands the memory usage from your strings in the file since internally the data will be stored as python objects (strings, integers, floats, in dictionaries).